# $F(c)$ can be written uniquely as $r(c)$ with $\deg r(x)<n$

Tags: field-theory

> $p(x)$ is irreducible, $c$ is a root pf $p(x)$. I have proved that every element in $F(c)$ can be written as $r(c)$ and sort of proved if $s(c)=t(c)$ in $F(c)$ where $s(x)$ and $t(x)$ have degree $<n$ then $s(x)=t(x)$ and now I want to conclude that every element in $F(c)$ can be written uniquely as $r(c)$ with $\deg r(x)<n$.

So I looked up what it meant to be unique and it just means that its the only possible solution. So wouldn't it be something like $z(c)/p(x)=p(c)q(c)+r(c)$ so $r(c)=-p(c)q(c)$?

Comment: Where you wrote $z(c)/p(x)=p(c)q(c)+r(c),$ might you have meant $z(c)=p(c)q(c)+r(c) \text{?} \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me restate what you've done, adding in some implicit information.

I take it that $F$ is meant to be a field, that $p(x)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $F$, that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$, that $c$ is a root of $p$ in some extension field of $F$, that $F(c)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $c$, and that you've proved every $\alpha$ in $F(c)$ can be written as $\alpha=r(c)$ for some polynomial $r(x)$ with coefficients in $F$. Also, I take it $n$ is meant to be the degree of $p$.

So now suppose $\alpha$ is in $F(c)$. Then $\alpha=s(c)$ for some polynomial $s$ with coefficients in $F$. By the Division Theorem, $s(x)=p(x)q(x)+r(x)$ for some polynomials $q,r$ with coefficients in $F$ and degree of $r$ less than degree of $p$. Letting $x=c$, we get $\alpha=r(c)$, and we're done.